# PostSharp: aspecting classes that implement certain interface

Tags: .net-4.5, postsharp

I can do the multiple declaration at AssemblyInfo.cs file at web service project, aspecting classs' method under specific namespace.

This is for my ASP.NET web api project.

I would like to aspecting through interface, stuffs that I want to subject to certain type of aspects, I will implement a specific interface (just a blank interface) at the class, then at the AssemblyInfo file, I will do something like:

```
[assembly: My.AOP.ValidateArguement(
//AttributeTargetTypes = "My.WebServices.Controllers.*"
AttributeTargetTypes = "My.WebServices.IWebApi"
, AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method
, AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public | MulticastAttributes.Instance
, AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public | MulticastAttributes.Instance
)]
```

And I tested ***this doesn't work***. AttributeTargetTypes only work for namespace.

When the web api class/controller grow, I can easily manage through Interface tagging to class.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply the aspect attribute to interface methods, you can also enable the propagation of this attribute to the methods implementing the interface in concrete classes. For this you need to set the `AttributeInheritance` property when applying the attribute. In your case it should be enought to set it to `MulticastInheritance.Strict`.

```
[assembly: My.AOP.ValidateArguement(
    AttributeTargetTypes = "My.WebServices.IWebApi",
    AttributeInheritance = MulticastInheritance.Strict
    /* ... */
)]
```

Please refer to [Understanding Aspect Inheritance](http://doc.postsharp.net/multicast-inheritance) documentation page for more information.